# How to edit a HTML page from Jenkins

Tags: php, html, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which generate a html page. I want to add some forms to that html page, in order to add some comments after job's execution. 
Is there a way for Jenkins to manage the data provided by these forms (at Submit action)?

Answer (score 0):

The closest plugin I can find that does what you're asking would be this one:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Page+Markup+Plugin

But this is admittedly not quite what you asked. I would say you may need to write a script that will make the modifications ot the HTML reports that Jenkins can run after compiliation of said reports.